# Apply changes from a Commit to a fresh checked-out branch

Tags: git

I am on branch `A`.  I have branch `B` which has commit `1eB4ad`.  I want all changes (the diff, the entire commit of `1eB4ad`) to be applied to `A`'s working tree and staging area.  So say commit `1eB4ad` added `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, then after this command, branch `A` will have `file1.txt`, and `file2.txt` in the working tree as well as tracked but un-added to the staging area/index.  Which command or series of commands can accomplish this end state?

Comment: that topic did wind up solving my problem, although i wouldn't have found it so easily because i didn't know cherry-pick was a necessary command.  So I worded my question as command-agnostically as I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cherry pick is the command you're looking for:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Without the commit use the -n flag:

`git cherry-pick -n 1eB4Ad`

Comment: i don't want to add the commit to branch `B` but just apply its changes.  So I believe `git cherry-pick -n <SHA>` will do that.  `-n` for no commit.  i'd accept your answer given that extra info, if correct.

Comment: Correct: `git cherry-pick -n 1eB4Ad` Will omit the commit and apply the changes to your working tree (and staging area). You can then make any further modifications and commit at a later time